# Redirect Wordpress posts to a new post title

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I have a Wordpress blog in which I want to rewrite the post titles.  The problem is that the permalinks will change, since they're based on the title, and inbound backlinks that reference the url that was created from the original title won't work.

What I need to do is rewrite the titles, but then create pages with the original permalink urls that redirect the reader to the new title, so that backlinks keep working.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: The WordPress [Redirection](http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) plugin has an option to automatically add a 301 redirect when you change a post's permalink, or you can configure any redirection manually in it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can think to do it is to add rules to your .htaccess or vhost file for Apache (or whatever http server you are using).

You can find many examples on the web using mod_rewrite.

[Redirecting and Remapping with mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html)

Doing a quick Google search on "wordpress permalink redirect" also turns up many result so how to handle this type of issue.